# Using IN operator with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to use `IN` operator for two columns.

Here is a query for one column:

```
select * 
from Mouvement_Final T 
where T.Comp_Id  in (select Comp_Id from Compte where Comp_Idcategorie='AOPT')
```

I would like filter when `Comp_Idcategorie='AOPT'` for the two columns `Comp_Id` AND `Comp_idcouleur`.

Comment: There is only *one* primary key. It may have multiple columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `exists`.  It generalizes much better.  For your code:

```
select T.* 
from Mouvement_Final T 
where exists (select Comp_Id
              from Compte c
              where c.Comp_Idcategorie = 'AOPT' and
                    c.Comp_Id = T.Comp_Id
             );
```

You should be able to see how this generalizes to more conditions.

Comment: *And* results in a better execution plan.

Comment: fast and efficient, this is the solution for me, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You may use `JOIN` with `distinct`

```
select distinct T.* 
from Mouvement_Final T
join Compte C on T.Comp_Id = C.Comp_Id and 
                 T.Comp_idcouleur = C.Comp_idcouleur and
                 C.Comp_Idcategorie = 'AOPT'
```

Comment: This will result in an expensive DISTINCT operation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, semi join is better